# Inserting multiple entities from single form

Tags: java, struts2

I want to insert multiple Person entities in a single HTML form. I want to use `Map<Integer, Person>` as the property in Action class. What should be the form input parameter names for this? The attributes of Person are id, name, age.

```
<form action="createPeople">
//person1
   <input type='text' name='{What is the name here?}' />
   <input type='text' name='{What is the name here?}' />
   <input type='text' name='{What is the name here?}' />

//person2
   <input type='text' name='{What is the name here?}' />
   <input type='text' name='{What is the name here?}' />
   <input type='text' name='{What is the name here?}' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of inserting content into a map.

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Input Test</h1>
        <s:form action="test">
            <s:textfield size="40" name="myMap[1]"></s:textfield><br/>
            <s:textfield size="40" name="myMap[2]"></s:textfield><br/>
            <s:textfield size="40" name="myMap[33]"></s:textfield><br/>
            <s:textfield size="40" name="myMap[444]"></s:textfield><br/>
            <s:textfield size="40" name="myMap[999]"></s:textfield><br/>
            <s:submit/>
        </s:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Action... Struts2 can make use of Generics for Type conversion

```
package com.quaternion.struts2basic.action.test;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test extends ActionSupport{
    //public to make example shorter
    public Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    public String exectute(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Warning... The following does what you expect that is [1] is treated as a number

```
<s:textfield size="40" name="myMap[1]"></s:textfield><br/>
```

['1'] is treated as a character but only if there is a single character ie '22' will be promoted to a string and thus the type conversion would convert '22' to 22 but '1' to 49 which is probably not what you want.

["1"] should work but in the struts tag the html which is written becomes :

```
<input type="text" name="myMap[&quot;1&quot;]" size="40" value="" id="test_myMap_&quot;444&quot;_"/><br/>
```

Which will not work.